# Difference between ListView and ListBox in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, listview, windows-8, listbox, microsoft-metro

What is the difference between "ListView" and "ListBox" in a "Windows 8" app.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `ListBox` is an older control primarily for compatibility with other xaml frameworks.  The `ListView` has build-in functionality for touch etc.  Use the `ListView` unless you have a specific need for the `ListBox`

See [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/WinAZ/archive/2012/02/13/windows-8-listbox-2-listview.aspx) for more detail.

**Specific events available only for `ListView`:**

[DragItemsStarting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.dragitemsstarting)

[ItemClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.itemclick)

**Methods:**

[CompleteViewChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.completeviewchange)

[CompeteViewChangeFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh702515)

[CompleteViewChangeTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh702517)

[InitializeViewChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.initializeviewchange)

[LoadMoreItemsAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.loadmoreitemsasync)

[MakeVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh702523)

[ScrollIntoView(Object, ScrollIntoViewAlignment)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh968031)

[StartViewChangeFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh702526)

[StartViewChangeTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh702527)

**Properties:**

[CanDragItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.candragitems)

[CanDragItemsProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.candragitemsproperty)

[CanReorderItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.canreorderitems)

[CanReorderItemsProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.canreorderitemsproperty)

[DataFetchSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.datafetchsize)

[DataFetchSizeProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.datafetchsizeproperty)

[Header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.header)

[HeaderProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.headerproperty)

[HeadTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.headertemplate)

[HeaderTemplateProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.headertemplateproperty)

[HeadTransitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.headertransitions)

[HeadTransitionsProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.headertransitionsproperty)

[IncrementalLoadingThreshold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.incrementalloadingthreshold)

[IncrementalLoadingThresholdProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.incrementalloadingthresholdproperty)

[IncrementalLoadingTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.incrementalloadingtrigger)

[IncrementalLoadingTriggerProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.incrementalloadingtriggerproperty)

[IsActiveView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.isactiveview)

[IsActiveViewProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.isactiveviewproperty)

[IsItemClickEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.isitemclickenabled)

[IsItemClickEnabledProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.isitemclickenabledproperty)

[IsSwipeEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.isswipeenabled)

[IsSwipeEnabledProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.isswipeenabledproperty)

[IsZoomedInView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.iszoomedinview)

[IsZoomedInViewProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.iszoomedinviewproperty)

Answer (score 5):

**`ListBox` is NOT obsolete.**

`ListBox` has many similarities with `ListView` or `GridView` (they share the parent class `ItemsControl`), but each control is oriented towards **different scenarios**. `ListBox` is best for general UI composition, particularly when the elements are always intended to be selectable, whereas `ListView` or `GridView` are best for data binding scenarios, particularly if virtualization or large data sets are involved.

*Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242868*

Comment: From the ListBox page at learn.microsoft.com: <br/>          "ListBox is useful when you are upgrading a Universal Windows 8 app that uses ListBox, and need to minimize changes. For new apps in Windows 10, we recommend using the ListView control instead." [link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listbox#definition