# Show status bar when using the ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindow windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

My Windows Phone 8.1 apps bottom part gets under the software navigation keys. I use  `ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindow` to make the page stay over the software navigation keys. But as a result the content of the page gets under the status bar and the status bar becomes transparent. Is there any way to keep the status bar normal and also make the page from going under the software navigation keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to keep the status bar normal and also make the page
>   from going under the software navigation keys?

`ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindow` can indeed help to display content under the navigation key. But if you want to avoid the side effect that your top status bar becomes transparent, you could try `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBoundsChanged` and change the margin of your page. If you have a look, The top margin is set to `-40` to go under the status bar you could just put that to `0` and set the `ApplicationView` as mentioned above that'll fix it.

You might refer to [this blog](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.sg/2014/12/a-behavior-to-deal-with-ui-consequences.html) written by @Joost Van where he demonstrates the detailed steps and code as well as the screenshot. And it works with your Windows Phone 8.1 project.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try this.

Comment: Hey @Mattew I was trying to customize my statusbar, The `Windows.UI.ViewManagement` doesn't contain the Statusbar definitions. Have they moved it to someother namespace? could you please help?